# Prove which set is bigger

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For numbers less than $10^7$, which set is bigger, set of numbers whose sum of digits are $31$ or set of numbers whose sum of digits are $32$?

I believe they are the same set cardinality, but I can't find a function that is a bijection between those two, $\overline{a_1 a_2 a_3 \dots a_7}$ and $\overline{b_1 b_2 b_3\dots b_n}$, don't have idea how can I relate $a_i$ and $b_i$.

Comment: Subtracting $1$ from the right-most digit that is non-zero?

Comment: This bound is small enough that it should be easy to directly test all numbers in the range and produce a direct count, brute force. Using a simple program, I mean -- not by hand.

Comment: Both sets contain 512365 numbers.

Comment: Also, what radix is intended, so "digits" makes sense?

Comment: @MariePierredeLeTetou: That doesn't work because 20 and 11 both get matched to 10

Answer (score 2):

Instead of numbers, left pad with zeros and consider seven digit strings. The sum of digits will not be affected.  Match up a digit string with sum $32$ with a digit string where each digit in the original string is subtracted from $9$.  The total will be subtracted from $9 \cdot 7=63$ and will therefore be $31$.  That is one bijection.